# Trying to update stock on Magento OMS using API

Tags: stock, inventory

I am trying to test out updating stock on the Magento OMS API by using the **magento.inventory.source_stock_management.update** method. The first step of getting the authentication token from the https://auth-stg.bcn.magento.com/oauth/token URL is working fine.

After that, I am doing a POST request on the service bus http://api-stg.mcom.magento.com (with the previously acquired token in the Authorization header). I am using the POST body format as given in the Inventory Snapshot example on https://omsdocs.magento.com/en/integration/introduction/

However, I am consistently getting the "404, URL not found" method. I tested the URL http://api-stg.mcom.magento.com and it is functional. Can anyone assist? Please note that I am trying with both a C# client as well as CURL.